# How to create target connection to load data from SQL Server to MS Access 2016 in Informatica Powercenter?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, informatica, informatica-powercenter

My goal is to load data from SQL Server to MS Access table.

Informatica Server is - Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.3
Informatica Version is - 10.2.0 Hotfix 1
MS Access Version - 2016
MS Access file location - Windows

Reading from SQL Server is no issue, but I am not able to figure out how to connect to MS Access database file that is in my local windows directory.

1. I created an ODBC connection in workflow manager and used dummy username and password. I am not sure if I have to use dummy credentials here either.

[ODBC connection in Informatica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3utA.jpg)

2. I created DSN in my local computer. Using the DSN, I was able to create Informatica target in mapping designer.

[ODBC DSN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su0FD.jpg)

[MS Target in Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcgQs.jpg)

3. When I run the wf, I get the below error. I probably need to update the ODBC.ini file in my informatica server. But I don't know what details I could use there e.g. which driver to use or other fields.

[Workflow Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEStc.jpg)

Error code: -

```
CMN_1022 [
[DataDirect][ODBC lib] Driver Manager Message file not found. Please check for the value of InstallDir in your odbc.ini.
Database driver error...
Function Name : Connect
Database driver error...
Function Name : Connect
Database Error: Failed to connect to database using user [test] and connection string [IFRSXTRACT].]
```

Can someone guide me if there are any other steps to establish connection to MS Access.

Comment: Maybe don't need connection. In VBA could do: `CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tablename IN 'filepath\db.accdb' SELECT * FROM tablename"`. How are you exporting data to Access? Is there equivalent Execute command in PowerCenter? Do you have full Access app available? Why not use Access to import?

Comment: I am using Informatica Powercenter so that I can read data from SQL Server, transforms it as per my logic and load to MS Access. Exporting data to Access is the goal and that is where I am unable to connect to MS Access through Informatica.

Comment: Informatica may be an overkill here. You can simply link SQL Server tables in Access, and access them (no pun) as regular MS Access tables, why not?